# Finding distribution function for a random variable defined by a conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to solved the following:

Find the distribution function of a random variable $\xi$ which takes positive
values and satisfies $P(\xi >x + y| \xi >x) = P(\xi >y)$ for all $x,y > 0$.

So far I know that $P(\xi >y) = P(\xi >x + y| \xi >x) = \frac{P( \xi > x+y \cap \xi > x)}{P( \xi >x)}.  $

I think I can say that $P( \xi >x)= 1-F_{\xi}(x)$, where $F_{\xi}(x)$ is the CDF of $\xi$.   How do I determine how to express the numerator of the quantity above.  I don't think $\xi >x + y$ and $\xi >x$ are independent.  Is there a way to express their joint distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $F$ as the distribution function of $\xi$, then you have

$$P(\xi>y)= 1-F(y)$$
$$P(\xi >x+y|\xi>y) = \frac{P(\xi>x+y)}{P(\xi>x)}=\frac{1-F(x+y)}{1-F(x)}$$

You can derive for $G=1-F$

$$G(x)\cdot G(y) = G(x+y),\ G(0)=1,\ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}G(x)=0$$

If you differentiate with respect to $x$ and set $x=0$, you get

$$G'(0)G(y)=G'(y)$$

i.e.

$$G'(y) = -\lambda G(y),\ \lambda = -G'(0),\ G(0) = 1$$

The solution of this [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) is

$$G(x)= e^{-\lambda x},\ \lambda > 0 $$

which is the [exponential failure distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_rate) (see also [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)). This function is commonly used to model lifetimes of lightblubs.

Answer (score 1):

The equality $P(ξ>x+y|ξ>x)=P(ξ>y)$ is called "Memorylessness" and is a describing property for the exponential distribution in the continuous case or geometric distribution in the discrete case.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Memorylessness

If you want to proof it:

1.) consider $P(\xi > x+y, \xi > x) = P(\xi > x+y)$

2.) So you get $P(\xi > y)\cdot P(\xi > x) = P(\xi > x+y)$

this is a functional equation which is (only) solved by an exponential